# How can i disable Admin UI in Wso2 servers?

Tags: wso2

I want to disable the UI of Wso2 servers . I can see EnableHTTPAdminConsole which is used for Http console in carbon.xml. Please suggest me a way from where Can i disable the admin UI for https too.

Answer (score 1):

What is meant by disable admin UI..?  you need to completely remove the UI of WSO2 server ? then i guess you can remove the all the front end features from the WSO2 server using feature manager as mentioned in WSO2 [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=31129740)

But, if you need to only disable access to the management console from external parties.  You can have proxy rules which disable the  `/carbon/` url.  If you disable the access to `/carbon/` from a proxy, then anyone can not access the management console through the proxy.